# Access a class attribute inside a python class decorator

Tags: python, class, decorator

***EDIT***: i found [this method decorator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Easy_adding_methods_to_a_class_instance) and was able to use it to individually wrap the methods (omitting `__init__`) of ClassA and ClassB. however, instead of manually wrapping individual methods, i'd like to just wrap the class.

i've created my own logging class, MyLogger, which inherits logging.Logger. in this class, (among other things) i have a FileHandler which prints the logger name in its output:

```
import logging

class MyLogger(logging.Logger):
    def __init__(self, name, path="output.log"):
        logging.Logger.__init__(self, name, logging.DEBUG)
        logpath = path

        fh = logging.FileHandler(logpath)
        fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        fh.setFormatter(logging.Formatter("%(name)s - %(message)s"))

        # stream handler omitted

        self.addHandler(fh)
```

i also have ClassA and ClassB, which both get the same instance of MyLogger:

```
class ClassA(object):
    def __init__(self, mylogger):
        self.log = mylogger

    def fn1(self):
        self.log.debug("message1 from ClassA fn1")
        self.fn2()
        b = ClassB(self.log)
        b.fn1()
        self.log.debug("message2 from ClassA fn1")

    def fn2(self):
        self.log.debug("message1 from ClassA fn2")

    # many more functions

class ClassB(object):
    def __init__(self, mylogger):
        self.log = mylogger

    def fn1(self):
        self.log.debug("message1 from ClassB fn1")

    # many more functions
```

here's a simple "main" function:

```
print "inside main"
log = MyLogger("main")
a = ClassA(log)
a.fn1()
```

because the MyLogger instance is being passed around, i'd like to ensure the log name (i'm just using the class name) is printed correctly by each function. so i'm attempting to decorate all methods of each class so that the the previous log name is remembered, then the log name is set to the name of the class, the method is run, and finally the log name is set back to what it previously was. i'm using the decorator/descriptor from [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Easy_adding_methods_to_a_class_instance). for the sake of brevity, i will only post my changes to it. i renamed the decorator setlogger, have added print statements inside each method in the descript class, and have altered `make_bound` as follows:

```
def make_bound(self, instance):
   print "in __BOUND__"
   @functools.wraps(self.f)
   def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
       '''This documentation will disapear :)'''
       prev = instance.log.name
       print "about to wrap %s.%s, prev = %s" % (instance.__class__.__name__, self.f.__name__, prev)
       ret = self.f(instance, *args, **kwargs)
       instance.log.name = prev
       print "done wrapping %s.%s, now = %s" % (instance.__class__.__name__, self.f.__name__, prev)
       return ret
   # This instance does not need the descriptor anymore,
   # let it find the wrapper directly next time:
   setattr(instance, self.f.__name__, wrapper)
   return wrapper
```

if i use the setlogger decorator/descriptor to wrap individual methods in ClassA and ClassB, it works fine. however, i'd like to just wrap the two classes. so here's my class decorator:

```
def setloggerforallmethods(cls):
    def decorate(*args, **kwargs):
        for name, m in inspect.getmembers(cls, inspect.ismethod):
            if name != "__init__":
                print "calling setattr on %s.%s" % (cls.__name__, name)
                setattr(cls, name, setlogger(m))
        return cls

    return decorate
```

if i wrap ClassA and ClassB with `@setloggerforallmethods`, and run the main function, heres the output:

```
inside main
calling setattr on ClassA.fn1
in __INIT__: f = fn1
calling setattr on ClassA.fn2
in __INIT__: f = fn2
in __GET__
in __UNBOUND__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/ws/maleva-rcd/yacht/classa.py", line 23, in <module>
    a.fn1()
  File "/ws/maleva-rcd/yacht/yachtlogger.py", line 34, in wrapper
    self.f.__name__)
ValueError: zero length field name in format
```

i dont understand why fn1 is unbound at this time. isnt it bound to a as in `a.fn1()`?

Comment: First, this is clearly Python 2.x, so you should always be using `class A(object):` to create new-style classes. You don't want to add the weird quirks of classic classes on top of whatever you're trying to debug.

Comment: Second, you should not be calling `logging.Logger.__init__` explicitly. If you want to construct a Logger, you do it the same way as any other type: call the class as a constructor. (If you meant for `MyLogger` to be a subclass of `logging.Logger`, that's different… but then you have to actually _make_ it a subclass.) And this means your code doesn't even run and exhibit the behavior you're asking about, it just gets a `TypeError` trying to pass a non-`Logger` as the `self` argument of `logging.Logger.__init__`.

Comment: And finally, there is nothing in your `ClassB` that initializes a new logger, or re-initializes an existing one, so the problem you're asking about can't possibly exist in your code.

Comment: Also, `self.log` is not a class attribute, it's an instance attribute. This means that every `ClassA` object (and every `ClassB` object, needless to say) has a different one. And just doing `fn = setlogger(fn)` doesn't do anything useful, it just creates a wrapped function, binds it to the local name `fn`, and then forgets it. If you want to monkeypatch the attributes of an object, you have to actually call `setattr` on the object.

Comment: @abarnert: If I understand his example right, he is creating a single logger beforehand and passing it as an argument to the constructor, so the same object will be shared as `self.log`.

Comment: @BrenBarn: Sure, but he seems to think the problem is that it's a class attribute, which isn't the problem; it's just that he's assigned the same value to two different variables. And, more importantly, since he never does anything to reconfigure that logger anyway, all of that is a red herring. Whatever the problem is in his actual code, it's (a) not in the code he showed us, and (b) not what he thinks it is.

Comment: Yeah, I don't understand what's going on with the "name".  I don't see anything that would change the logger name except the "fix" that's supposed to stop it from changing it.

Comment: @abarnert: 1) updated ClassA and ClassB to new-style (logging.Logger is a new style) 2) i did mean for it to be a subclass. updated MyLogger to inherit logging.Logger. however, calling super fails since logging.Logger inherits logging.Filterer and logging.Filterer's __init__has a different signature. 3) sorry, left out this code. updated.

Comment: @user2251357: Your edited code still doesn't demonstrate the problem. It may just be because you forgot to call `addHandler` anywhere, so you've just got a logger with no handlers and a handler that you create and destroy without ever using, but I don't want to try to guess at what your code does and end up solving the wrong problem. Please read [Minimal, Complete, Valid Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also, why do you want `ClassA` and `ClassB` to share a logger, but both set its `name`, in the first place? That's a very odd thing to do—and it seems like it's not what you want to happen. It's like the old joke, "Doctor, it hurts when I go like this." "So don't go like that." If you can explain what you're trying to accomplish (see [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)) maybe we can show you a better way to accomplish it.

Comment: @abarnert: sorry, i have nearly 2000 lines of code that i'm trying to simplify for this post. apparently, im having a tough time providing working code. :) my code kicks off a 'main' class, which in turn instantiates about 5 other classes. i figured passing one logging object around would be simpler than duplicating the code necessary to instantiate a logger with multiple handlers in each class. perhaps its the wrong way to go about it?

Comment: @user2251357: Duplicating what code? The code to instantiate a logger is one line, which you do in your top-level code: `log = MyLogger("main")`. Is the only reason you're trying to share a logging object because you don't know how to pass around a logging factory (which your `MyLogger` class already is) instead?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to solve the wrong problem in the wrong way. But I can explain why your code isn't doing what you're trying to make it do.

---

First, in your decorator, you do this:

```
for name, fn in inspect.getmembers(cls, inspect.ismethod):
    if name != "__init__":
        print "calling setlogger on %s" % cls.__name__ + "." + name
        fn = setlogger(fn)
```

That has no effect. For each bound method `fn`, you create a wrapper function, then rebind the local variable `fn` to that function. That has no more effect than doing this:

```
def foo(a):
    a = 3
i = 0
foo(i)
```

If you want to set an attribute on the class, you have to set an attribute on the class, like this:

```
setattr(cls, name, setlogger(fn))
```

Now your wrapper will get called.

---

Next, `cls.log` is a class attribute named `log`—that is, an attribute on the class itself, which is shared by all instances of that class. But all of the code within the classes uses *instance* attributes, where each instance has its own copy. That's what you get when you assign `self.log` in your `__init__`. So, there is no class attribute named `log`, meaning you'll just get this:

```
AttributeError: type object 'ClassA' has no attribute 'log'
```

You could of course create a class attribute… but that won't do any good. The instance attribute of the same name will just shadow it.

You need to access the instance attribute inside `inner`, which means you need a `self` to access it off. And you obviously don't have `self` inside `setlogger`. But think about what you're doing: you're wrapping a method with another method. Methods get `self` as their first argument. In fact, if you modify `inner` to print out its `args`, you'll see that the first one is always something like `<__main__.ClassA object at 0x12345678>`. So:

```
def inner(self, *args, **kwargs):
    prevname = self.log.name
    self.log.name = cls.__name__
    ret = func(self, *args, **kwargs) # don't forget to forward self
    self.log.name = prevname
    return ret
```

---

But if any of these wrapped methods ever raises an exception, they'll leave the name in the wrong state. So really, you need to either create a context manager for stashing and restoring the value, or just a `try`/`finally`. Which also happens to make the wrapper a little easier to write:

```
def inner(self, *args, **kwargs):
    prevname = self.log.name
    self.log.name = cls.__name__
    try:
        return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
    finally:
        self.log.name = prevname
```

---

Finally, you need to remove the `self.log.name =` in each `__init__` method. Otherwise, when you construct a `B` instance in the middle of `A.fn1`, you're changing the logger's name without going through the wrapper that restores the previous name.

---

Again, I don't think this is a good solution. But it will do what you're trying to do.

Comment: looks like our posts crossed. the descriptor above works for individually wrapping class methods, but what I gather from your response is it's possible to do this without a descriptor. I will try explicitly using the self arg as well as the try finally.

Comment: also, if I'm goin about this the wrong way, please do suggest a better way. all I want is multiple classes to use a logger to log info, warnings, etc to the console and log debug to the _same_ file. the format for logging to the file includes the name of the class which logged it

Answer (score 0):

I still don't completely understand the problem you're trying to solve, but I think it's this:

Constructing a `MyLogger` takes two pieces of information: a name, and a path. You don't want every class to have to know that path. So, you figured you needed to share the `MyLogger` instance, because there's no other way around that. And then, because the `MyLogger` stores its name as an attribute, you had to hack up that attribute in wrappers around every method.

But there is a much simpler way around that: Make your classes take a "logger factory"—that is, a callable which constructs an appropriate logger for them—instead of a logger. The `MyLogger` class itself already *is* such a callable, since it takes a default value for `path` and you just use it. But let's pretend that weren't true, and you wanted to use some non-default `path`. Still easy; you just need to wrap it up:

```
class ClassA(object):
    def __init__(self, log_factory):
        self.log_factory = log_factory
        self.log = log_factory("ClassA")
    def fn1(self):
        # ...
        b = ClassB(self.log_factory)
        # ...

class ClassB(object):
    def __init__(self, log_factory):
        self.log_factory = log_factory
        self.log = log_factory("ClassB")
    # ...

# or just log_factory = functools.partial(MyLogger, log="output.log")
def log_factory(name):
    return MyLogger(name, "output.log")
a = ClassA(log_factory)
a.fn1()
```

You may notice that the `__init__` method in both classes does the same thing. So, why not extract it into a mixin base class?

```
class LogUserMixin(object):
    def __init__(self, log_factory):
        self.log_factory = log_factory
        self.log = log_factory(self.__class__.__name__)
```

Now:

```
class ClassA(LogUserMixin):
    def fn1(self):
        # ...
```

When it's a `ClassA` being initialized, `self.__class__` will be `"ClassA"`, not `"LogUserMixin"`, so this does exactly what you want. It works even if your real classes already have base classes, or a hierarchy of subclasses, or if they do additional stuff in `__init__`, or take additional arguments; you just need to do a tiny bit more work in some of those cases.